# Linking dependent .so files with ndk-build for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have created a .so file that exposes a native C call to Java via JNI. This works well and I can deploy the app onto my Android system if I just use system libraries in my C code. However, if I want to make calls to functions in other .so files, I cannot get my project to link correctly.

For example, say I have the "libotherso.so" file which contains APIs defined in C that I can call from the "MyJNILibrary.c" code I'm using to generate "libMyJNILibrary.so".

I tried to change my Android.mk file as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := MyJNILibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyJNILibrary.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lotherso

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But when I call ndk-build on this, I get errors finding -lotherso. Where do I put the "libotherso.so" file so that ndk-build can pick it up?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := otherso
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../lib/libotherso.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := MyJNILibrary
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := MyJNILibrary.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := otherso
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Note that LOCAL_SRC_FILES is relative to your LOCAL_PATH.

Don't forget to load your dependency before your own JNI library:

```
static {
  System.loadLibrary("otherso");
  System.loadLibrary("MyJNILibrary");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a new directory called "lib" in my project and copied the libotherso.so file there. I also updated the Android.mk file as you have suggested as well as loaded the "otherso" library before "MyJNILibrary". ndk-build gets further than it did before, but there is still an error:

Comment: I should also mention that I had copied the otherso.h file into my jni folder where MyJNILibrary.c resides. I also recompiled the java code that now loads both libraries with the appropriate "javac" and "javah -jni" calls before calling ndk-build. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, I'm not trying to make calls into "libotherso.so" from my java code. I'm trying to make C calls into "libotherso.so" from the MyJNILibrary.c code that is used to make "libMyJNILibrary.so".

Comment: Posting the error output would help.  You'll still have to loadLibrary  libotherso.so before using it from MyJNILibrary.

Comment: christine@christine-ubuntu:~/workspace/OtherSoSampleApp$ /home/christine/Downloads/android-ndk-r8d/ndk-build APP_ABI=x86 /home/christine/Downloads/android-ndk-r8d/build/core/add-application.mk:128: Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-14 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml Compile x86    : MyJNILibrary <= MyJNILibrary.c Prebuilt       : libotherso.so <= jni/../lib/ SharedLibrary  : libMyJNILibrary.so

Comment: /home/christine/Downloads/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ./obj/local/x86/objs/MyJNILibrary/MyJNILibrary.o: in function init:jni/MyJNILibrary.c:37: error: undefined reference to 'OtherSoAPI'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/x86/libMyJNILibrary.so] Error 1

Comment: OtherSoAPI is a C function from a prebuilt library that I am calling from MyJNILibrary.c. It has not been exposed via JNI, but I'm not trying to call it from my Java code. I'm trying to call it from my MyJNILibrary.c code. How can I tell the linker that the OtherSoAPI C calls (non-JNI) are in the libotherso.so file? Basically, I have written JNI code to expose a C call that in turn makes C API calls that are in libotherso.so. Those API calls are defined in the libotherso.h file I'm including. I'm basically trying to create a JNI wrapper to libotherso.so. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It is failing to link using the x86 toolchain.  Where did you get the libotherso.so binary from?  x86 is uncommon, I suspect you're trying to link against an ARM binary.  You must provide 1 binary .so file for each architecture you intend to support, and can place them in separate folders using the $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI) macro.  If it is an ARM binary try restricting your build to ARM by editing Application.mk, setting "APP_ABI := armeabi".

Comment: The libotherso.so is an x86 library, and that's what I'm trying to link to. That's why I'm calling ndk-build with the APP_ABI=x86 parameter. Are you saying that is incorrect? If I do not try to add in code that calls the libotherso.so library, then I do see my libMyJNILibrary.so file in the libs/x86 directory. But as soon as I try to include the libotherso.so API calls, I get the link error.

Comment: Make sure lib/ is in the same folder as your jni/ folder - i.e. the same folder that you run ndk-build from.  Check that libotherso.so exports the OtherSoApi method using i686-linux-android-objdump -t lib/libotherso.so.  Verify the linker parameters are correct by running V=1 ndk-build.

Comment: When I run "./i686-linux-android-objdump -t" from /home/christine/Downloads/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin on /home/christine/workspace/OtherSoSampleApp, I get the following message: "/home/christine/workspace/OtherSoSampleApp/lib/libotherso.so: file format elf32-i386" and "SYMBOL TABLE: no symbols". Does this mean that libotherso.so file does not export the APIs I'm trying to call from MyJNILibrary.c?

Comment: Yes, there's a problem with your prebuilt library's export symbols.